# Identity Server 3 Token Request from POSTMAN Http Tool

Tags: postman, identityserver3

Using `POSTMAN`, I'm struggling to to retrieve my `Identity Server 3` token.

Error code is : `400 Bad Request`

Here are the details:

`POST` /identity/connect/token HTTP/1.1

`Host:` localhost:44358
`Content-Type:` application;x-www-form-urlencoded

`Cache-Control:` no-cache

`Postman-Token:` 57fc7aef-0006-81b2-8bf8-8d46b77d21d1

`username`=MYUSER-ID&`password`=MY-PASSWORD&`grant_type`=password&`client_id`=rzrwebguiangulajsclient&`client_secret`=myclientsecret&`redirect_uri`=https://localhost:44331/callback

I've done something similar with a simple Visual Studio 2015 WebApi project, where the end point was `\token`.

[image]

Any guidance/advice is appreciated...

regards,
Bob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm happy to say that we got Postman to work.

It turns out I was so close to getting `Postman` to work with Identity Server 3 Authorization.

The final piece to the solution was setting the Postman client  `Flow` to `Flow = Flows.ClientCredentials` (see the `postmantestclient` client definition below):

```js
using System.Collections.Generic;
using IdentityServer3.Core.Models;

namespace MyWebApi.MyIdentityServer.Config
{
public static class Clients
{
public static IEnumerable<Client> Get()
{
 return new[]
 {
  new Client
  {
   ClientId = MyConstants.MyIdentityServer.MyWebGuiClientId,
   ClientName = "My Web Gui Client",
   Flow = Flows.Implicit,
   AllowAccessToAllScopes = true,

   IdentityTokenLifetime = 300,
   AccessTokenLifetime = 300,  //5 minutes
   RequireConsent = false,

   // redirect = URI of the Angular application
   RedirectUris = new List<string>
   {
    MyConstants.MyIdentityServer.MyWebGuiUri + "callback.html",
    
    // for silent refresh
    MyConstants.MyIdentityServer.MyWebGuiUri + "silentrefreshframe.html"
   },
   PostLogoutRedirectUris = new List<string>()
   {
    MyConstants.MyIdentityServer.MyWebGuiUri + "index.html"
   }
  },
  new Client
  {
   ClientId = MyConstants.MyIdentityServer.SwaggerClientId,
   ClientName = "Swagger Client",
   Flow = Flows.Implicit,
   AllowAccessToAllScopes = true,

   IdentityTokenLifetime = 300,
   AccessTokenLifetime = 300,  
   RequireConsent = false,

   // redirect = URI of the Angular application
   RedirectUris = new List<string>
   {
    "https://localhost:44358/swagger/ui/o2c-html"
   }
  },
  new Client
  {
   ClientId = "postmantestclient",
   ClientName = "Postman http test client",
   Flow = Flows.ClientCredentials,
   AllowAccessToAllScopes = true,

   IdentityTokenLifetime = 300,
   AccessTokenLifetime = 300,  //5 minutes
   RequireConsent = false,

   ClientSecrets = new List<Secret>
   {
    new Secret("PostmanSecret".Sha256())
   },

   RedirectUris = new List<string>()
   {
    "https://www.getpostman.com/oauth2/callback"
   }
   }
 };
}
}
}
```

Comment: You wrote `setting the Postman client Flow to Flow = Flows.Implicit`, but 3rd client has `Flow = Flows.ClientCredentials,` - please clarify :)

Comment: @ignacy130 - good catch. I'm sure what happened there. I'm must have made a typo. I updated my answer to show that `Flows.ClientCredentials` was used in the client definition where `ClientId = "postmantestclient"`.

Answer (score 9):

The minimum required for a Resource Owner OAuth request is the following (line breaks added for readability):

POST /connect/token

Header

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

Body

```
username=MYUSER-ID
&password=MY-PASSWORD
&grant_type=password
&client_id=rzrwebguiangulajsclient
&client_secret=myclientsecret
&scope=api
```

Off the bat you are not requesting a scope in your request. Otherwise there is most probably something wrong in the configuration of your client within Identity Server.

Your best bet would be to [enable logging](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/configuration/logging.html) and look at what comes back when this request errors.

Update: also, [please don't use the ROPC grant type](https://scottbrady91.com/OAuth/Why-the-Resource-Owner-Password-Credentials-Grant-Type-is-not-Authentication-nor-Suitable-for-Modern-Applications)

Comment: Right, so I added a `scope` after I posted this, and still getting the `400 Bad Request` back. The dev already added Identity Svr logging as well, and now I'm seeing a `No matching hashed secret found` issue. so I might be passing the wrong values.

Comment: Yeah, that error is spot on, your client_secret is wrong. Don't forget it should be hashed in your Client configuration (see the .Sha256 helper method on string that Identity Server provides)

Comment: using Fiddler to capture the local http traffice, it shows the various HTTPS GET requests to Identity Server. However there are various steps involved, so I'm not convinced yet that I can request a TOKEN using a tool like POSTMAN. It seems very difficult.

Comment: I can configure the ClientSecrets property in the IdentityServer client configuration (i.e. `new Secret("MySecret".Sha256()` ) ) - however, how do I encode this on the Postman client side ?

Comment: Guys, I know its very late but I do get a token in Postman but when I call my API with the token I get forbidden error. Anything that I am missing?

Comment: @Saurabh 403 forbidden means that you have a valid token, but it's failing an authorization policy in your API